# How to ack more messages in Google pubsub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, message-queue, publish-subscribe

I've GCP pub/sub system with flow control setting configured because each message has a status parameter so I've to process the message individually. The ack is working fine but it's kind of slow compared to the message getting published. Here's the screen shot from the GCP pubsub metric.[image]

When I checked the CPU usage and below 50%

[image]

How can I increase the subscriber ACK count without affecting the message's sequential order?

My subscription code is similar to:

```
const subscriptionNameOrId = 'subscriber';
const maxInProgress = 1;

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

// Creates a client; cache this for further use
const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

async function subscribeWithFlowControlSettings(
  subscriptionNameOrId,
  maxInProgress
) {
  const subscriberOptions = {
    flowControl: {
      maxMessages: maxInProgress,
      allowExcessMessages: false
    },
  };

  // References an existing subscription.
  // Note that flow control settings are not persistent across subscribers.
  const subscription = pubSubClient.subscription(
    subscriptionNameOrId,
    subscriberOptions
  );

  console.log(
    `Subscriber to subscription ${subscription.name} is ready to receive messages at a controlled volume of ${maxInProgress} messages.`
  );

  const messageHandler = async message => {
    console.log(`Received message: ${message.id}`);
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    console.log("Done")
    message.ack();
  };

  subscription.on('message', messageHandler);
}

(async() => {
   await subscribeWithFlowControlSettings(subscriptionNameOrId, maxInProgress)
})()
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't ack messages at all, it nacks them, which will cause the messages to be redelivered. But even if it acked I don't understand what kind of answer you are expecting, since you want to handle them sequentially on a single machine, the only possible answer is 'make your code or machine handle each message faster'. This has nothing to do with pubsubs ack mechanism, unless the ack rpc is the limiting factor, in which case you can batch them, but that is clearly not the bottleneck here.

Comment: Sorry I've corrected the code (I was debugging), so you're saying if I deploy another server with a subscriber, would it solve my problem?

Comment: If you can handle messages in parallel then yes that is a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

The publisher sends messages to the Pub/Sub topic. Pub/Sub delivers this message to all subscriptions. Each subscription has an acknowledgement deadline, which determines how much time is allocated for the client to acknowledge this message before the server redelivers it.

When `acknowledgement latency is high` it usually means messages are taking a long time to process by the subscribers. So to reduce ack latency, you can consider the following, reduce the message processing time by optimization and parallel processing, increase the number of subscribers and reduce network latency. For maximum throughput and lowest latency you can also consider using [StreamingPull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#service_apis).

For more information you can refer to these [link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KObJkda4ZfY),[link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCkwo6eEHIg) and [link3](https://medium.com/javarevisited/gcp-how-to-achieve-high-performance-synchronous-pull-with-pub-sub-and-spring-boot-12cb220c4d65).